# web2py: textareas lose initial newline

Tags: html, forms, newline, web2py

I'm not sure if this is a web2py problem or a general html problem, but when I create a form in web2py that contains an editable string in a textarea, and the string contains an initial newline, like `"\nsecond_line"`, the textarea does not display or save the newline - it is cut out. It works fine if there is a character before the newline: `"firstline\nsecond_line"` shows as on two lines. It is also only relevant for the *first* newline. If I have a string like `"\n\nthird_line"`, then the textarea shows a single newline at the start.

This is with the most recent (non beta) version of web2py, on safari 9.1.3 and chrome 56.0.2924.87.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. "By HTML 4.0 appendix B chapter 3.1, “a line break immediately following a start tag must be ignored, as must a line break immediately before an end tag. This applies to all HTML elements without exception.”"